# How can I get a Discord bot to use lines from a .txt file?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I was commissioned for making a bot for a music-themed server, and I'm gonna make commands for providing YouTube and Spotify links to some songs and also commands for sending an embed with lyrics of songs. The problem with this is that I have to do it for around 400 songs. I think there is a way to use a .txt file with all the links and make the bot send them one by one, and that would save me a lot of time. Please if you know how to do it, tell me and explain how it works.

Comment: How is the text file formatted? You can easily to `fs.readFile("path")` to get the contents of the file, and then split it into an array and use a loop

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all of your links inside of a .json file instead.

You could make it look like this :

```
{
    "links": [
              "link1",
              "link2",
              "and so on"
             ]
}
```

Then require it inside your code for further use
(`const json = require('path/to/yourFile.json');`) :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that :)